# How to put local pictures from an input file to DIV WinJS VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro app in WinJS which selects images by using an input file

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>e-Camera</h1>
        <br />
        <button              id = "imageCaptureButton">Tomar Foto</button>
        <input type = "file" id = "uploadCaptureInputFile" accept="image/*" />
        <br />
        <button             id = "uploadCaptureButton">Subir Foto</button>
        <br />
        <br />

        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

I want to print on my div `<div id="result"></div>` inside the result of the picture

this is my javascript file

```
function getDomElements() {
        _imageCaptureButton     = document.querySelector("#imageCaptureButton");
        _uploadCaptureInputFile = document.querySelector("#uploadCaptureInputFile");
        _uploadCaptureButton    = document.querySelector("#uploadCaptureButton");
        _divPicture             = document.querySelector("#result");
    }

function wireEventHandlers() {
        _uploadCaptureInputFile.addEventListener("change", loadPictureFromFile, false);
    }

app.onloaded = function () {
        getDomElements();
        wireEventHandlers();
        _uploadCaptureButton.disabled = true;
    }
```

---

and the method which is designed for loading the image:

**EDIT:** thanks to  jakerella and several modifications, here it is the anwser:

```
function loadPictureFromFile(event) {

    var selectedFile    = event.target.files[0];
    var reader          = new FileReader();

    imageElement = document.createElement("img");               //creates <img id="img"> element
    imageElement.title = selectedFile.name;                     //set photo's name

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        imageElement.setAttribute("src", event.target.result);  //picture's source
        _divPicture.appendChild(imageElement);                  //Add's <img> element to Div element
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a question here... are you asking how to load a file from an input? If so, maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153675/1985406

Comment: thats the answer, I wanted a method for loading a picture inside a div by using input file for selecting it thanks!!!!

Comment: Note that loading up an entire image file to display in a smaller space incurs greater memory overhead than necessary. If you can obtain a StorageFile object for the filename, then you can use StorageFile.getThumbnailAsync or getScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync (Windows 8.1), and display that result. A thumbnail can be passed to URL.createObjectURL and the return value from that assigned to an img.src. This typically performs faster as well because thumbnails are cached by the system indexer.

Comment: I need image full quality because I want to send it over a webservice :)