# Insert a photo to <img> by opening <input type = "file">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tell me, please, how can a photo be inserted to `<img>`, when I open 
`<input type = "file">` and choose any file ?
How can I use JS / JQuery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading an image to a <img> from <input file>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814231/loading-an-image-to-a-img-from-input-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'FileReader' object:

```
$("#yourinput").change(function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#yourimg").attr("src", e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```