# Preview images before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with four images for the user to select. I want the user to be able to preview each image on the site before upload.

The JavaScript code below works for only one image but I would like it to work for multiple images uploaded via `<input type="file">`.

What will be the best way to do this?

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#output').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#file-input").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for you to use something like [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin?

Comment: Just don't use a single `#output` image?

Comment: an example of your sugestion will be great@bergi

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here is **jQuery** version for you. I think it more simplest thing.

```js
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

Comment: @Artem Solovev, can we set maximun number of images in your above solution ?

Comment: How can i add a delete here?

Comment: @ArtemSolovev How to get `i` value inside reader onload? `alert(i)` will get result same value

Comment: just a little change I added `$("div.gallery").html("");` at top of my function so that each time when a file is selected previous thumbnails will be removed

Comment: It shows same picture again if user select the same picture more than on time.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani it wasn't mentioned in the task, so if you want - fix it

Answer (score 46):

- Add the **`multiple` attribute**  to your HTMLInputElement
- Add the **`accept` attribute** to your HTMLInputElement
  To filter your files selection to **images only**, use `accept="image/*"`, or a comma separated MIME list: `accept="image/png, image/jpeg"`
- Use [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to get the **Base64** string,
  or [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to get the file **Blob** object

---

#### Using FileReader.readAsDataURL

The **asynchronous** way to read the image data is by using `FileReader` API and its `readAsDataURL` method which returns a [**Base64**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) String:

```js
const preview = (file) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = fr.result;  // String Base64 
    img.alt = file.name;
    document.querySelector('#preview').append(img);
  };
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
};

document.querySelector("#files").addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
  if (!ev.target.files) return; // Do nothing.
  [...ev.target.files].forEach(preview);
});
```

```css
#preview img { max-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

#### Async strategy:

Due to the asynchronous nature of FileReader, you could implement an `async/await` *strategy*:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);


// Preview images before upload:

const elFiles = el("#files");
const elPreview = el("#preview");

const previewImage = (props) => elPreview.append(elNew("img", props));

const reader = (file, method = "readAsDataURL") => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => resolve({ file, result: fr.result });
  fr.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
  fr[method](file);
});

const previewImages = async(files) => {
  // Remove existing preview images
  elPreview.innerHTML = "";

  let filesData = [];

  try {
    // Read all files. Return Array of Promises
    const readerPromises = files.map((file) => reader(file));
    filesData = await Promise.all(readerPromises);
  } catch (err) {
    // Notify the user that something went wrong.
    elPreview.textContent = "An error occurred while loading images. Try again.";
    // In this specific case Promise.all() might be preferred over
    // Promise.allSettled(), since it isn't trivial to modify a FileList
    // to a subset of files of what the user initially selected.
    // Therefore, let's just stash the entire operation.
    console.error(err);
    return; // Exit function here.
  }

  // All OK. Preview images:
  filesData.forEach(data => {
    previewImage({
      src: data.result, // Base64 String
      alt: data.file.name // File.name String
    });
  });
};

elFiles.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
  if (!ev.currentTarget.files) return; // Do nothing.
  previewImages([...ev.currentTarget.files]);
});
```

```css
#preview img { max-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

#### Using URL.createObjectURL

The **synchronous** way to read the image is by using the `URL` API and its `createObjectURL` method which returns a [**Blob**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

```js
const preview = (file) => {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);  // Object Blob
  img.alt = file.name;
  document.querySelector('#preview').append(img);
};

document.querySelector("#files").addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
  if (!ev.target.files) return; // Do nothing.
  [...ev.target.files].forEach(preview);
});
```

```css
#preview img { max-height: 120px; }
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Although looks much simpler, it has implications on the main thread due to its synchronicity, and requires you to manually use (when possible) [**URL.revokeObjectURL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) in order to free up memory:

```js
// Remove unused images from #preview? Consider also using
URL.revokeObjectURL(someImg.src); // Free up memory space
```

#### jQuery example:

A jQuery implementation of the above `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` example:

```js
const preview = (file) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = (ev) => {
    $('#preview').append($("<img>", {src: fr.result, alt: file.name}));
  };
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
};

$("#files").on("change", (ev) => {
  if (!ev.target.files) return; // Do nothing.
  [...ev.target.files].forEach(preview);
});
```

```css
#preview img { max-height: 120px; }
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Additional read:

- [File API — Using files from web applications *(MDN)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications)
- [readAsDataURL *(MDN)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)
- [FileReader result *(MDN)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result)
- [Promise.all() *(MDN)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Preview Image, get file size, image height and width before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload)

#### Tips:

Besides using the HTMLInputElement attribute `accept`, if you want to make sure within JavaScript that a file *is-of-type*, you could:

```js
if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
   // Not a valid image
}
```

or like:

```js
if (!/^image\//i.test(file.type)) {
   // File is not of type Image
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you it is working fine.  how we can add a delete option for this?

Comment: @matheenulla by removing a "thumbnail / preview" image Element from the DOM does not mean you have removed it from your `FileList` assigned to that input type="file" element - and as such be submitted to the server. My suggestion is to stash the entire operation and start all over. At least that's the simplest way. See the expanded example above.

Answer (score 7):

```js
function previewMultiple(event){
        var saida = document.getElementById("adicionafoto");
        var quantos = saida.files.length;
        for(i = 0; i < quantos; i++){
            var urls = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
            document.getElementById("galeria").innerHTML += '<img src="'+urls+'">';
        }
    }
```

```css
#galeria{
        display: flex;
    }
    #galeria img{
        width: 85px;
        height: 85px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        opacity: 85%;
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple onchange="previewMultiple(event)" id="adicionafoto">
<div id="galeria">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

HTML:

```
<div id='photos-preview'></div>
<input type="file" id="fileupload" multiple (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" />
```

JS:

```
 function handleFileInput(fileList: FileList) {
        const preview = document.getElementById('photos-preview');
        Array.from(fileList).forEach((file: File) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
              var image = new Image();
              image.src = String(reader.result);
              preview.appendChild(image);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    }
```

[DEMO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL#Live_Result)

Comment: How could we use it for multiple separate input tags? not single input with multiple image preview

Comment: Hi Giorgi, use a forEach for FileList and a new FileReader to readAsDataURL on any file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

```js
function previewImages() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  
  if (this.files) {
    [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
  }

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var image = new Image();
      image.height = 100;
      image.title  = file.name;
      image.src    = this.result;
      preview.appendChild(image);
    });
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
  }

}

document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Your second example is an exact **copy** of an existing ([now edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39440179/revisions)) answer. Please refrain from such answering behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function previewImages() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  
  if (this.files) {
    [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
  }

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var image = new Image();
      image.height = 100;
      image.title  = file.name;
      image.src    = this.result;
      preview.appendChild(image);
    });
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
  }

}

document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: I am using your approach to detect the types, but it's throwing an alert and adding the file anyway. How Can I avoid this? Thank you!

Comment: This is an exact **copy** of an existing ([now edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39440179/revisions)) answer. Please refrain from such answering behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var upcontrol = {
  queue : null, // upload queue
  now : 0, // current file being uploaded
  start : function (files) {
  // upcontrol.start() : start upload queue

    // WILL ONLY START IF NO EXISTING UPLOAD QUEUE
    if (upcontrol.queue==null) {
      // VISUAL - DISABLE UPLOAD UNTIL DONE
      upcontrol.queue = files;
      document.getElementById('uploader').classList.add('disabled');
      // PREVIEW UPLOAD IMAGES
       upcontrol.preview();*enter code here*
      //PROCESS UPLOAD ON CLICK 

    $('#add_files').on('click', function() {
       upcontrol.run();
    });
    }
  },
  preview : function() {
    //upcontrol.preview() : preview uploading file
        if (upcontrol.queue) {
            var filesAmount = upcontrol.queue.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                  var fimg = document.createElement('img') 
                    fimg.src =  event.target.result,
                      fimg.classList = "col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 float-left center",
                      document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(fimg);                
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(upcontrol.queue[i]);
            }
        }
    },
  run : function () {
  // upcontrol.run() : proceed upload file

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        data = new FormData();
    data.append('file-upload', upcontrol.queue[upcontrol.now]);
    xhr.open('POST', './lockeroom/func/simple-upload.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {

      // SHOW UPLOAD STATUS
      var fstat = document.createElement('div'),

          txt = upcontrol.queue[upcontrol.now].name + " - ";
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // SERVER RESPONSE
          txt += xhr.responseText;
        } else {
          // ERROR
          txt += xhr.statusText;
        }
      }
      fstat.innerHTML = txt;
      document.getElementById('upstat').appendChild(fstat);

      // UPLOAD NEXT FILE
      upcontrol.now++;
      if (upcontrol.now < upcontrol.queue.length) {
        upcontrol.run();
      }
      // ALL DONE
      else {
        upcontrol.now = 0;
        upcontrol.queue = null;
        document.getElementById('uploader').classList.remove('disabled');
      }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  // IF DRAG-DROP UPLOAD SUPPORTED
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    /* [THE ELEMENTS] */
    var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');

    /* [VISUAL - HIGHLIGHT DROP ZONE ON HOVER] */
    uploader.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      uploader.classList.add('highlight');
    });
    uploader.addEventListener("dragleave", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      uploader.classList.remove('highlight');
    });

    /* [UPLOAD MECHANICS] */
    // STOP THE DEFAULT BROWSER ACTION FROM OPENING THE FILE
    uploader.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // ADD OUR OWN UPLOAD ACTION
    uploader.addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      uploader.classList.remove('highlight');
      upcontrol.start(e.dataTransfer.files);
    });
  }
  // FALLBACK - HIDE DROP ZONE IF DRAG-DROP UPLOAD NOT SUPPORTED
  else {
    document.getElementById('uploader').style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
```

i used somthing like this and i got the best result and easy to understand.

Comment: <p id="uploader" class="">Drag Here</p>
 
                  <div id="gallery" class=""></div>
                  <br>
                  <div id="upstat"></div>
                   <input id="add_files" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Images" name="add_files"> use this for the html drag-in-uploader

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendRows(){
    $i++;
    var html='';
    html+='<div id="remove'+$i+'"><input type="file" name="imagefile[]" accept="image/*" onchange="appendloadFile('+$i+')"><img id="outputshow'+$i+'" height="70px" width="90px"><i onclick="deleteRows('+$i+')" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></div>';
     $("#appendshow").append(html);
}

function appendloadFile(i){
    var appendoutput = document.getElementById('outputshow'+i+'');
    appendoutput.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59985954/8784402

#### ES2017 Way

```js
// convert file to a base64 url
const readURL = file => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => res(e.target.result);
        reader.onerror = e => rej(e);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
};

// for demo
const fileInput = document.createElement('input');
fileInput.type = 'file';
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.attributeStyleMap.set('max-width', '320px');
document.body.appendChild(fileInput);
document.body.appendChild(img);

const preview = async event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const url = await readURL(file);
    img.src = url;
};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', preview);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery">
```

```js
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.