# Preview images in yii2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I want to implement in my yii2 app somethink like that:
[How to preview multiple images before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439760/how-to-preview-multiple-images-before-upload)
I need to show multiple images(max 5)
Whats wrong with my code? When I choosed file nothing happened.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p class="add_photo"><img class="describe_images" src="photo.png"></img>Добавить фото(до 5 штук)</p>
            <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
            <script>
            function previewImages() {
              var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
              if (this.files) {
                [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
              }
              function readAndPreview(file) {
                // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
                if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                  return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
                } // else...
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                  var image = new Image();
                  image.height = 100;
                  image.title  = file.name;
                  image.src    = this.result;
                  preview.appendChild(image);
                }, false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

              }
            }
            document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);
            </script>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 pixels-line">
            <div class="preview"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);` try `.addEventListener("click", previewImages, false);`. As clicking on the UI button does nothing, the element would have to have a DOM change for the event listener to execute currently.

Comment: I have that error always
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at FileReader.<anonymous> (index.php:130)
at line:
preview.appendChild(image);

Comment: That's because document.querySelector('#preview') is returning null.  You have a div with class="preview", not id="preview", so the proper query is document.querySelector(".preview")