# How to upload files from the same directory as index.html into an element with <input type="file"> by clicking on a button of another element

Tags: javascript, html

**Edit**

Maybe I'll try to break the issue into smaller ones:

1. How to upload files from the same directory as index.html.
2. How to upload a file into an element with `<input type="file">` by clicking on a button in another element.
3. How to customize the button from the second issue, which is probably easier once the first two issues are dealt with.

**The original question**

I'm trying to find a way to upload two files from code-provided paths into two elements with `<input type="file">` attributes from a button of another element, so no dialog box for browsing files should be opened.

I couldn't find ways to do that. Maybe the issue phrasing was the reason. Maybe that's impossible. I don't have a lot of experience with HTML.

The files' elements code:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" >
<textarea id="file1_txt" name="file1_txt" rows=8 cols=50></textarea>

<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" >
<textarea id="file2_txt" name="file2_txt" rows=8 cols=50></textarea>
```

The other element's button code:

```
<button type="button" "style="color:red;font-weight:bold;height: 35px;font-size:14">Load example</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439760/how-to-preview-multiple-images-before-upload

Comment: Use label tag and for attribute. You could style labels as buttons

Comment: @Mario , maybe that's a good direction. I think I still need to eliminate the file selection dialog window.

Comment: @Mario can you refer to an example?

Comment: I apologize, I did not read your question correctly, what I suggest is related to how to locate a file without having to click the button directly